# Keep the last worksheet of all the .xlsx within one folder

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have few `.xlsx` files in a folder. Each file contains over 30 worksheets. I'm trying to keep a specific sheet (same name) in each file (usually the last sheet of each file).

The code below only works on one file in the folder; it does not go through each of them.

```
import openpyxl, glob

for file in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
for sheetName in wb.worksheets:
    if sheetName.title != 'abc':
        wb.remove(sheetName)
wb.save(file)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is incorrect. In Python indentation signals the end of a code block

```
import openpyxl, glob

# This loops through all of the workbooks
for file in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)

# Now, once all of the workbooks have been looped through, only the last one is edited
for sheetName in wb.worksheets:
    if sheetName.title != 'abc':
        wb.remove(sheetName)
wb.save(file)
```

Try this

```
import openpyxl, glob

for file in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    for sheetName in wb.worksheets:
        if sheetName.title != 'abc':
            wb.remove(sheetName)
    wb.save(file)
```